# Is there any way to specify a struct's attribute as a function's parameter?

Tags: rust

Here is the struct `Area` that I am using for a Snake program:

```rs
struct Area {
    max_x: usize,
    max_y: usize,

    arr: Vec<Vec<&'static str>>
}
```

And here is the function that uses the `arr` attribute from the struct `Area`:

```rs
fn refresh(area: &Area) {
    println!("{:?}", area.arr)
}
```

Since it only needs that one attribute from the struct, I was hoping that I could have the parameter be that one named attribute so that I wouldn't have to write as much.  It would look like this (This produces an error):

```rs
fn refresh(array: &Area.arr) {
    println!("{:?}", array)
}
```

Is there any workaround to doing something similar to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can change the signature of your `refresh` function like so

```rust
fn refresh(area_arr: &Vec<Vec<&'static str>>) {
    println!("{:?}", area_arr)
}
```

and then you can call it like this

```rust
refresh(&your_area_instance.arr);
```

Here is a full code example

```
struct Area {
    max_x: usize,
    max_y: usize,

    arr: Vec<Vec<&'static str>>
}

fn main() {
    let area_instance = Area {
        max_x: 20,
        max_y: 20,
        arr: vec![
            vec![&"test1_1", &"test1_2"],
            vec![&"test2_1", &"test2_2"],
        ]
    };
    refresh(&area_instance.arr);
}

fn refresh(area_arr: &Vec<Vec<&'static str>>) {
    println!("{:?}", area_arr)
}
```

and a [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6a5da14ca236cabbd55b1793ad44cda7).